# Are there only two smooth manifolds with field structure: real numbers and complex numbers?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, fields, smooth-structures

Is it true that in the category of connected smooth manifolds equipped with a compatible field structure (all six operations are smooth) there are only two objects (up to isomorphism) - $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: What about finite fields (considered as discrete 0-dimensional manifolds). Am I missing something?

Comment: @SamGunningham Yes, they are not connected.

Comment: Sorry, missed that asssumption!

Comment: Well, they can be equipped with a topology that makes them connected... But in that case they are not manifolds modelled on $\mathbb{R}^n$, is that what you have in mind ? (I must confess I don't know where the theory of smooth manifolds breaks over $\mathbb{Q}$)

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Yep, a non-discrete finite topological space is not a real manifold. Yes, the question is about that.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Probably $\mathbb{Q}$-manifolds are bad, because the smoothness of the function $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ does not guarantee any standard theorems about it. For example, $f (x) = -1$ on $x < \sqrt{2}$ and $f (x) = 1$ on $x > \sqrt{2}$ is infinitely differentiable in the sense of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a series of standard arguments.

Let $(\mathbb{F},+,\star)$ be such a field. Then $(\mathbb{F},+)$ is a finite-dimensional (path-)connected abelian Lie group, hence $(\mathbb{F},+) \cong \mathbb{R}^n \times (\mathbb{S}^1)^m$ as Lie groups. Since $\mathbb{F}$ is path-connected, there is in particular a path $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb{F}$ with $\gamma(0) = 0_{\mathbb{F}}$ and $\gamma(1) = 1_{\mathbb{F}}$. Now consider the homotopy $H: \mathbb{F} \times [0,1] \to \mathbb{F}$, $(x,t) \mapsto \gamma(t) \star x$. This gives a contraction of $\mathbb{F}$ and so we can exclude all the circle factors.

Now, fix $y_0 \in \mathbb{F}$ and consider the map $\widehat{y_0}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \mapsto x \star y_0$. Then $\widehat{y_0}$ is an **additive** map (but at the moment not necessarily linear with respect to the natural vector space structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$). It is not too difficult to see that by additivity we have $\forall q\in \mathbb{Q}: \widehat{y_0}(qx) = q \widehat{y_0}(x)$. Since $\widehat{y_0}$ is continuous (as being smooth), it *now* follows that it's actually $\mathbb{R}$-**linear**.

Thus $\mathbb{F}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. From this point on one can finish either by the Frobenius theorem on the classification of finite-dimensional *associative* $\mathbb{R}$-algebras or invoke a theorem of Bott and Milnor from algebraic topology that $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be equipped with a bilinear form $\beta$ turning $(\mathbb{R}^n,\beta)$ into a division $\mathbb{R}$-algebra (not necessarily associative) only in the cases $n=1,2,4,8$.

**EDIT:** Another finishing topological argument is a theorem of Hopf saying that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are the only finite-dimensional commutative division $\mathbb{R}$-algebras. This is less of an overkill compared to invoking Frobenius or Bott–Milnor as the proof is a rather short and cute application of homology, see p.173, Thm. 2B.5 in Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology".

Comment: It's beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: @EschatumVerus: Happy to help! :-)

Comment: You don't really need connected, just positive dimensional with smooth multiplication. If you pick some $x\ne 0$ in the path component of $0$, and divide by $x$, you take the $x$ path component to the $1$ path component, but you fix $0$. So $0$ and $1$ are on the same path component. Then your homotopy above shows there is only one path component.

Comment: @BenMcKay: nice observation that one can weaken the initial hypothesis on $\mathbb{F}$!

Comment: One can have even less "overkill", because the question was specifically about fields and the only finite field extensions of $\mathbb{R}$ are $\mathbb{R}$ itself and $\mathbb{C}$ which is an easy consequence of the fact that all real polynomials of odd degree have a real root.

Comment: @JohannesHahn: I was secretly looking for a topologically flavoured argument to match the rest, but you are completely right, of course :-)

Comment: Is the intermediate value theorem not topological enough? :-)

Comment: @JohannesHahn: Touché :-)

Answer (score 5):

Finite-dimensional manifolds are locally compact, and the only non-discrete locally compact topological fields are the reals and the complex numbers.  So the answer is yes.

Comment: Hmm, it seems p-adic numbers are also a locally compact field https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_field

Comment: Here is the complete classification https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jjm1924/19/2/19_2_189/_pdf

Comment: Thus, it remains to analyze two cases: the field of p-adic numbers and the division ring of formal power series over the Galois field in those cases when it is a field (see the link for details).

Comment: Of course, the $p$-adic numbers are not connected (in fact totally disconnected, though not discrete, so that the statement exactly as written is indeed false).

Comment: If formal power series (I guess meaning Laurent polynomials?) over a finite field are given their topology coming from the valuation, then they, too, are totally disconnected.

Comment: Yes, p-adic ones are homeomorphic to a Cantor set without a point => are not path-connected. I do not quite understand howthe last division ring is defined (how is the automorphism used there and why is this a division ring )

Comment: The formal power series over a field (a finite field or infinite field) form a commutative ring.  If you pass to its fraction field you get the Laurent series over that field.  It is strange (in English) to refer to that as a division ring when you don't have any actual noncommutative division rings under discussion too: it's better to call $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf Q_p$, $\mathbf F_p((t))$, and their finite extension *fields* rather than division rings.

Comment: @KConrad The article at the link says
«..the (in general non-commutative) field of formal power
series..»‎
Doesn't "non-commutative field" mean the devision ring?